# Get output of parts of PS in one single CSV line

Tags: linux, csv, ps, text-formatting

I need to collect the CPU consumption of some processes that match a string but i need it on a single line separated by comman and was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible to do in one single `ps`/`grep`/`awk` command.

Use case:

- **Command I'm using**:

```
ps aux | grep tx | grep -v grep | awk {'print $11":"$3'}
```

- **Output**:

```
/opt/tx/bin/server:5.2
/opt/tx/bin/engine:1.2
/opt/tx/bin/agent:0.3
```

- **What I needed to get**:

```
/opt/tx/bin/server:5.2,/opt/tx/bin/engine:1.2,/opt/tx/bin/agent:0.3
```

Cheers all

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect using this:

```
ps -e -o command,pcpu | awk -v OFS=: -v ORS=, '/tx/ {print $1, $NF}' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

This filters columns using `ps` options, uses AWK to filter the output, keep the first and last entries on each matching line, and change the field and record separators, and replaces the trailing comma with a newline.

Comment: Amazing answer and a quick one, cheers to you !

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it (by clicking the currently greyed-out checkmark on the left) so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.